# addEventListener('click') на элементы ли

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', function() {
 instrColor = 'red';
    console.log(instrColor);
})
document.getElementById('blue').addEventListener('click', function() {
 instrColor = 'blue';
    console.log(instrColor);
})
document.getElementById('green').addEventListener('click', function() {
 instrColor = 'green';
    console.log(instrColor);
})
document.getElementById('yellow').addEventListener('click', function() {
 instrColor = 'yellow';
    console.log(instrColor);
})
document.getElementById('pink').addEventListener('click', function() {
 instrColor = 'pink';
    console.log(instrColor);
})
document.getElementById('brown').addEventListener('click', function() {
 instrColor = 'brown';
    console.log(instrColor);
})
document.getElementById('black').addEventListener('click', function() {
 instrColor = 'black';
    console.log(instrColor);
})
document.getElementById('orange').addEventListener('click', function() {
 instrColor = 'orange';
    console.log(instrColor);
})
```

```css
.colors {
      height: 70px;
      width: 70px;
     }
    #red {
     background-color: red;
    }
    #blue {
     background-color: blue;
    }
    #green {
     background-color: green;
    }
    #pink {
     background-color: pink;
    }
    #black {
     background-color: black;
    }
    #brown {
     background-color: brown;
    }
    #yellow {
     background-color: yellow;
    }
    #orange {
     background-color: orange;
    }
        li {
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     padding: 10px;
     margin: 0 15px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="colors" id="black"></li>
 <li class="colors" id="red"></li>
 <li class="colors" id="blue"></li>
 <li class="colors" id="green"></li>
 <li class="colors" id="yellow"></li>
 <li class="colors" id="pink"></li>
 <li class="colors" id="orange"></li>
 <li class="colors" id="brown"></li>
</ul>
```

фрагмент кода вот такой, задача чтобы при клике на цвета, instrColor менялся на соответствующее значение(или на id элемента ли).
Javascript-овая часть моей реализации мне не особо нравится, как можно его укоротить или сделать как нибудь по элегантней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в списке не будет других элементов то можно добавить листенер на сам список и проверять какой именно элемент в нем кликнули

```js
document.getElementById('colorsList').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var element = e.target
  instrColor = element.id;
  console.log(element.id);
  console.log(instrColor)
})
```

```css
.colors {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}

#pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

#black {
  background-color: black;
}

#brown {
  background-color: brown;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul id="colorsList">
  <li class="colors" id="black"></li>
  <li class="colors" id="red"></li>
  <li class="colors" id="blue"></li>
  <li class="colors" id="green"></li>
  <li class="colors" id="yellow"></li>
  <li class="colors" id="pink"></li>
  <li class="colors" id="orange"></li>
  <li class="colors" id="brown"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ!!